# Сохранение данных в H2 в Spring Boot

Tags: java, h2

Как сделать чтоб после перезапуска приложения, данные добавленные в текущей сессии сохранились и были загружена в следующий раз. Я так понимаю надо добавить какой-то параметр в application properties.

Comment: есть такой антипатерн "Щедрые остатки". Случай, когда один unit-тест создаёт данные, которые где-то сохраняются, а другой тест их потом переиспользует. Если «генератор данных» будет по какой-то причине вызван позже или пропущен, то тест, использующий его данные, не пройдёт. 
Тесты должны быть независимыми

Comment: Не понял привязки тестирования к моему вопросу. Можно конкретнее?

Comment: может быть я неправильно понимаю вашу задачу. в основном, h2 используют для тестирования своего приложения. и если это так, то нельзя хранить данные, которые выполняют одни тесты, и использовать эти данные для других тестов.

Comment: h2 не всегда используют для тестирования. Все равно спасибо,не знал про такой антипатерн.

Answer (score 0):

необходимо указать путь к файлу с параметрами

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:file:~/test2;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE;AUTO_RECONNECT=TRUE
```